# Javascript to track amount of audio listened in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am currently trying to use Javascript to record how much of an audioclip someone chooses to listen to on my Qualtrics survey. However, for some reason the code that I have keeps returning all 0s (both in the console log as well as in the embedded data file). I am still very new to Javascript and would greatly appreciate another set of eyes!

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page loads*/
    function roundNumber(number, digits) {
        var multiple = Math.pow(10, digits);
        var rndedNum = Math.round(number * multiple) / multiple;
        return rndedNum;
    };

    // variables to keep track of progress
    var audioListened = 0;
    var audioSkipped = 0;
    var lastPosition = 0;

    // initialize data to 0
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('totalTime', 0);

    var audio_element = jQuery("audio.qmedia") // HTML audio element to track

    // as the audio plays, we update the data with the total amount of time listened
    audio_element.ontimeupdate = function(event) {
        audioListened = event.currentTime - audioSkipped;
        lastPosition = event.currentTime;
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('totalTime', roundNumber(audioListened, 2));
    };
    console.log(audioListened, audioSkipped);


    // when participant skips time, we keep track of this to subtract from total time
    audio_element.onseeked = function(event) {
        audioSkipped = (event.currentTime - lastPosition); // adds fast-forwarding, subtracts rewinding from total
    };
    console.log(audioListened, audioSkipped);

});
```

Comment: Are you sure `audio_element.ontimeupdate` is getting triggered? How are you calling it?

Comment: `audio_element` is a jQuery object. Typically one adds event handlers to those like `audio_element.on('timeupdate', function (event) { ... });`, not by adding a property.

Comment: Yes, this is very likely the cause of the entire problem. The other thing is that the query may return no elements and still you won't notice any difference, because you're setting property on empty collection/array/jQuery object.

Comment: Thank you @HereticMonkey, that worked! I am now getting action on the console log. However, this is still not getting written into the embedded data field. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I have no idea how Qualtrics works. I'd move your `console.log` just above your `setEmbeddedData` call so that you're logging at the time the event is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to handle this is to use the [`played` property of the media element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-media-played).  It gives you a [TimeRanges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TimeRanges) object that you can use to figure out what parts have been watched/listened to.

```
for (let i=0; i<audio.played.length; i++) {
  // Logs something like:  0, 5.3333
  console.log(audio.played.start(i), audio.played.end(i));
}
```

Here's a working JSFiddle example:  https://jsfiddle.net/qhryjz82/